# Swift/Firebase Database invalid token error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Experiencing some rather odd issues with Firebase.. I have installed firebase through cocoaPods, included the GoogleService-Info.plist, etc - but when I try to read a value from Firebase, I get this error:

> 2016-06-16 12:10:04.598 MP[78421:13128189] [FirebaseDatabase] Authentication failed: invalid_token (Invalid claim 'aud' in auth token.)

I have gotten this every single time I have tried to start a new project, except from one time - but I have abandoned that project now, as I am starting a new one. Here is the simple code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
            var val = snapshot.value! as? String
            print(val)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error message indicates that the project in the token doesn't match the project that your app is connecting to. From a [post on the firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/KLQWr2VRjRE):

> There are a couple ways you may hit this:
>
> 1. You've changed your GoogleService-Info.plist to point at a different project, but your app still has a cached token from a previous run.
> 2. I believe the iOS Simulator shares the keychain between apps, so if you have multiple apps using Firebase, one app might be picking up the token cached by another app.  This *only* happens in the simulator and we're working on changing the Firebase SDK to avoid this.
>
> In either case, you can probably resolve the issue by doing an explicit `signOut()` call before initializing Firebase Database.

Comment: I did a FIRAuth.auth()?.signout - and now everything works! Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Happens on device too. Cleared sim, did signout on both versions of the app. Still complains about the token. No idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when I want send OTP and get notifications, I created APN key on apple developer console then added it to firebase after that everything got well:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWal9.png)