# Invalid token because of wrong audience?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just made a firebase project, installed the pods and got the googleplist in, configured it in the app delegate, and set it up exactly like I have other projects.

For my pods, I've got exactly what I have in my main other project :

```
pod 'Firebase/Core’
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
```

When I run this code :

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.setValue("hello")
```

I get an error that pops up like 50 times that says :

MyProjectName[209384092:9028304928034randomnumbers] [FirebaseDatabase] Autentication failed: Invalid_token (audience was project 'a random project from my firebase console' but should have been project 'myProjectName'.

I thought maybe I had done something really goofy at first, so I deleted my project entirely and reinstalled a new google.plist and redid everything, but the only thing that has changed is now I'm just getting a different random project from my firebase project list.

What's goin' on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error as you got, but it only occurred in simulator.

To fix this issue I had to reset my simulators content and settings.

[image: simulator - reset content and settings...]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is experiencing this issue on an actual iPhone device rather than the simulator the root cause of this issue is provided in another SO thread:

[Swift/Firebase Database invalid token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857131/swift-firebase-database-invalid-token-error?rq=1)

It looks Firebase plan to address it in a future SDK update but to resolve it for now you must sign-out + invalidate your Firebase Database session in your 'old' project first:

```
NSError *error;
[[FIRAuth auth] signOut:&error];
if (error) {
    ELog(@"Firebase Logout failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Your 'new' project should then now function as expected.

Comment: I really had faith that this would work; but it didn't. Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you deleting your 'old' project app after signing out before installing and launching the 'new' project app?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not taking the correct apiKey and authDomain. Go to Firebase, select the project go to Authentication and then Web Setup and see if the apiKey and authDomain are the same keys that you are using in the firebase.initializeApp({});