# Getting Authentication failed: invalid_token (audience was project ' ' but should have been project ' ')

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Using firebase with google as a client for firebase auth. After I successfully generate a token from firebase, I'm trying to display a set of data from another firebase database. The above error occurs when I'm trying to fetch data from that database.

However, if I do whatever is suggested in: [Swift/Firebase Database invalid token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857131/swift-firebase-database-invalid-token-error?rq=1), I'll be logging out, won't that not defeat the whole purpose of using Auth from firebase? Or Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a Firebase ID token from one project to access the database of another project?

Comment: Yes, that is the use case.

Comment: Then this is the expected behavior. You should stick to the same project, or create your own mechanism to convert the ID token of one project to a custom token for another project.

Answer (score 0):

`xcrun simctl erase all` on terminal then

`command + option + shift + k` on xcode